# Outlook Meeting room booking from c# web application

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, conference, meeting-request

I am developing a asp.net we. Application using Microsoft exchange services, where in i have conference room booking module from which user can book the available conference room for specified duration, now we want to integrate this with Outlook meeting room, where in user can able to book the conference room from our application or Outlook  both data should sync.. kindly suggest me the good approach to do the same ... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using EWS Impersonation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/impersonation-and-ews-in-exchange. You can then always impersonate the Organizer of the Meeting and create the meeting in their calendar and send the Invitation to the Meeting room which should the AutoAccept if everything is setup correctly and the Meeting is within the booking policy.

Comment: Thank you so much glen scales.. how to sync my application with Outlook